# How to Include "django-forms-bootstrap" in your requirements file

Tags: django, stripe-payments, django-apps, requirements.txt

I'm trying to setup django-strip-payments.  My process is install an app using pip to my env then add it to my settings INSTALLED_APPS. I don't know how to complete the following step though: "Include "django-forms-bootstrap" in your requirements file."
   Where is this requiremnts file.  Does it allow me to have apps that are not directly in my django file tree such as my other apps I have made from scratch?  This was the first step in the Quick Start guide for django_forms_bootstrap and the more information I can get on what's happening the better.  I have never used other apps besides the ones I've made or have been provided by django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's talking about a `requirements.txt` file.  It's a file that contains pip packages, one per line.  A user can install the packages by running:

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

So you would need to add this file and add the line

```
django-forms-bootstrap
```

to it.